# Organizing date format (non-Gregorian calendar) - Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, date, jalali-calendar

I have a large sales database the first column of which is the purchase date. The problem is some of these dates are entered in `DD.MM.YY` format, some in `YY.MM.DD` and some in `YYYY/MM/DD`. I want to make them all to same format. What is the cleanest way I can do this?

Note 1: I'm thinking of doing a series of `if`s but that would be a lot of conditions so I'm wondering if there is a cleaner shortcut.

Note 2: An additional complication is that the dates are in Jalaali calender and not Gregorian. I have the function that will convert them to gregorian but I need to pass the correct `year, month, day` arguments to it; this is why I want to bring them all to a single format. But additionally, this means that if you offer some "Gregorian-only" solutions, like `dateutil.parser`, it might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting this I found/thought of a solution myself, but instead of deleting the question I decided to post the answer in case someone else come to a similar problem.

tl;dr - I just added a century option to `dateutil.parser`. I didnt know how to but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38577299/9573918).

Here's my end code:

```
from khayyam import JalaliDate
from dateutil.parser import parse, parserinfo

class MyParserInfo(parserinfo):
    def convertyear(self, year, *args, **kwargs):
        if year < 100:
            year += 1300
        return year

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt = parse("9.12.96", MyParserInfo()).date()
    a=JalaliDate(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day).todate()
    print(dt)
    print(a)

#1396-09-12
#2017-12-03
```